Draw a coordinate line
I want to draw numerical intervals like in this picture. If it is possible, the arrow style should be the same as in the picture.


what you try so far?

Welcome to TeX.SX! This site is not meant to be a human-powered image-to-TikZ conversion tool. You got some answers in the meantime but please do add some code that shows what you tried so far in order not to have this and possible future questions closed.

As a frame for possible starting point:

\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,
                arrows.meta, 
                patterns.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, draw, fill=#1, inner sep=1pt, node contents={}},
dot/.default=white,
  S/.style = {pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={2pt}]},
              pattern color=cyan},
every label/.append style = {font=\footnotesize, text height=1.3ex, inner sep=1pt}
                        ]
\draw[-Stealth] (0,0) -- (6,0);
\path   (2,0) node (a) [dot=black,label=below:$a$] (4,0) node (b) [dot=black, label=below:$b$]; 
\scoped[on background layer] 
\path[S]    (a) rectangle   ([yshift=2mm] b);
%
\draw[-Stealth] (0,-1) -- (6,-1);
\path   (2,-1) node (a) [dot,label=below:$a$] (4,-1) node (b) [dot, label=below:$b$];
\scoped[on background layer]
\path[S]    (a) rectangle   ([yshift=2mm] b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


I prefer to reserve tkz-euclide for Euclidean geometry, but it can be used here with the same styles as TikZ.
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}

\def\tkzHachSegment[#1](#2,#3){%
\tkzDefShiftPoint[#3](0,2pt){tkztempx}
\tkzDefParallelogram(a,b,tkztempx) \tkzGetPoint{tkztempy}
\tkzFillPolygon[#1](#2,#3,tkztempx,tkztempy)
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{hach style/.style = { pattern       = {Lines[angle=45,
                      distance      = {2pt}]},
                      pattern color = black}}                  
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/a,6/0/b}
\tkzDrawLine[-Stealth](a,b)
\tkzDrawPoints(a,b)
\tkzHachSegment[hach style](a,b)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


